# Shadow appear in left menu on IIViewDeckController in iOs 8

Tags: ios8, xcode6

In my app with xCode 5 and iOs 7 all works fine, but yesterday I installed xCode 6 and swipe to left sideview of my App shows a shadow in the up-left corner with 150px height and 200px height approximate. This shadow appear at the end of transition to left sideview.

No new version for IIDeckViewController is on GitHub. Anybody knows how to remove this wrong effect in iOs 8?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue is solved with IIDeckViewController release 2.11, available on GitHub.

You can download [here](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck/releases/tag/2.2.11)

Comment: is that version fully compatible with iOS8? Im solving portrait orientation in landscape mode with ViewDeck. Thanks

Comment: Oddly enough, the issue returns in the latest release 2.3.1.

Comment: Ref [https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck) version 2.3.1 is buggy, and version 2.2.11 should be used. Had to downgrade to this version to fix the issue.